# javascript button on click show loader

Tags: javascript, button, loader

I am using javascript to complete a command which sometimes takes a long time to accomplish, but when I click the button, the button stays pushed and does not update the screen until the javascript execution is complete. I need to know how to continue updating the screen while executing the javascript, because I want to show a loader while executing the javascript.

Code: [jsFiddle code](http://jsfiddle.net/TSUcs/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image doesn't show because the browser will ensue a redraw/repaint only after the current Javascript stack ends.

What you can do is showing the loader and using a [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout) to call your heavy-processing function after the repaint has taken place.

Note that if your function executes synchronous actions such as a `for` loop `100000000` times as in your fiddle, your browser will be too busy processing it to animate a loading image (you'll have a static image then).

```
onclick="show_loader(); setTimeout(fn, 100);"
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/TSUcs/4/)

Comment: @Cameron No problem. `=]` I increased the timeout to 0.1 secs now as it wasn't showing correctly on my Nightly 17, at least now it animates the image a little before the processing takes place.You may increase it a little, say half second `0.5` to give a loading feel if you'd like. `:)`

Answer (score 1):

use jQuery. The jQuery.click will get an on click action, then use jQuery's toggle with a div that contains a loading gif inside the click function.